# What is the maximum height for an image to load in a website on iPad

Tags: css, image, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max image width in Mobile Safari? Getting unwanted downscaling on panos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720316/max-image-width-in-mobile-safari-getting-unwanted-downscaling-on-panos)

What is the maximum height for an image to load in a website in iPad. 
I load an image(a sprite) with exceeding height of 7500px and it doesn't show on iPad browser.
When I reduce the height then it start to show.

Fyi, the sprite is a collection of small icons and i using compass to generate it.

Answer (score 2):

This article talks about a 2 megapixel limit **bug** on the iPad. It's not about max height - it's about the max pixel count.

http://duncandavidson.com/blog/2012/03/webkit_retina_bug

The solution: use progressive jpegs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk in all Mobile Safari Browsers: Image size may not be more than 1024x1024x3 pixels, independently of the ratio. defusion.org says it must not be more than 2,000,001 pixels.

Putting that in perspective: your sprite with the height of 7500px may not be wider than 2000000/7500 = 266px. fotr not being scaled down on the ipad/iphone

Here's some more detail on it:
http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/

and the story behind it:
http://www.teknocat.org/blog/web-development/show/6/mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk